# ¿Como puedo bloquear una ip a un archivo php de redireccion?

Tags: php, datetime, redirección, ip, time

Este es mi archivo de redireccion en php

```
<?php
header("Location: https://www.ejemplo.org/anuncio1.php");
?>
```

¿Que codigo necesito para que cuando una persona con una ip. por ejemplo 192.168.1.1 solo pueda ser redireccionado 1 vez al dia o una vez por hora a ese archivo `anuncio.php`, y cuando lo intente por segunda vez en un determinado tiempo. lo envie por ejemplo a `https://wwww.ejemplo.org/solosepermiteunavisitaporhora.php` o le imprima un mensaje que diga: Ya visitaste esta web recientemente, vuelva en 1 hora.

Comment: Puedes guardar en su navegador un localstorage, o tal vez una cookie

Comment: Qué pasa en el caso en el que el usuario / usuarios lleguen desde una LAN que sale a Internet y lleguen a tu página desde una única IP pública? Necesitas identificar al usuario o realmente no importa mucho / son todos de la misma red local con el servidor?

Answer (score 0):

**primero deberias tener la ip del cliente algo asi :**

```
<?php $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];?>
```

**validar**

```
 if($ip == "192.168.1.10") {
    die("Lo sentimos, estas baneado . $ip"); 
  }
```

esa seria una forma sencilla, ademas podrias crear un listado de ips bloquedas en un array o a su vez en una base de datos

Comment: La cosa es que yo no necesito banear a alguien o bloquear manualmente su ip. lo que quiero hacer es que esa persona pueba ver un anuncio por hora, el enlace del anuncio vaya dentro del php de redireccion. y cuando ese usuario vaya intente abrir nuevamente ese anuncio en menos de una hora, lo envie a otra pagina por ejemplo ustedyavioesteanuncioenlaultimahora.php, que se guarde la ip de un usuario en una base de datos, por 1 hora y luego lo deje redirigir una vez mas